# Collection of comboBoxes in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, user-controls

I am working on small winforms app. One of my forms contains few comboBoxes:

[image]

As I am trying to use MVP pattern in my project, so I decided to create View and Presenter for that form. The communicate via adequate interface.

ComboBox can be fully decribed (for my needs) with its DataSource (i.e. list os strings) and SelectedIndex. That' s why I created proper interface:

```
public interface IMyView
{
    MyViewPresenter { set; }

    IEnumerable<string> ComboBox1stDataSource { get; set; }
    int ComboBox1SelectedIndex { get; set; }

    IEnumerable<string> ComboBox2ndDataSource { get; set; }
    int ComboBox2ndSelectedIndex { get; set; }
    //for third comboBox it will be the same
}
```

I implemented that interface in my View class:

```
public partial class MaterialDatabasePropertiesForm : Form, IMaterialDatabasePropertiesView, IMyView
{

    public MaterialDatabasePropertiesPresenter Presenter { private get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<string> ComboBox1stDataSource
    {
        get { return comboBox1st.DataSource as List<string>; }
        set { comboBox1st.DataSource = value; }
    }
    public int ComboBox1SelectedIndex
    {
        get { return comboBox1st.SelectedIndex; }
        set { comboBox1st.SelectedIndex = value; }
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> ComboBox2ndDataSource
    {
        get { return comboBox2nd.DataSource as List<string>; }
        set { comboBox2nd.DataSource = value; }
    }
    public int ComboBox2ndSelectedIndex
    {
        get { return comboBox2nd.SelectedIndex; }
        set { comboBox2nd.SelectedIndex = value; }
    }
}
```

When everything is set like above  I use properties declared in Interface in my Presenter to change properties of comboBoxes in form.

Although it may seem like a good solution it isn' t enough for me. In my origial application I have 14 comboBoxes, and that number may change in future.

What I am trying to is making it more elastic. I was thinking about creatin some collection of comboBoxes in view, but I can' t figure it out.

My sample solutin is bad, as it doesn' t even compile:

```
private List<List<string>> collectionOfComboBoxesDataSources = new List<List<string>>()
        {
            ref comboBox1st.DataSource,         //  I get error:
            ref comboBox2nd.DataSource,         //  "Cannot acces non-static field
            ref comboBox3rd.DataSource          //   <comboBoxName> in static context"
        };

    //this property would be part of IMyView
    public List<List<string>> CollectionOfComboBoxesDataSources
    {
        get { return collectionOfComboBoxesDataSources; }
        set { collectionOfComboBoxesDataSources = value; }
    }
```

What can I do to create collection (or something working similar) to acces my comboBoxes properties?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to iterate through your form.

```
List<ComboBox> listOfCombobox = new List<ComboBox>();

foreach(var combobox in this.controls.OfType<ComboBox>())
{
       listOfCombobox.Add(combobox);
}
```

If you're trying to do this.
Then you can access the list via index, so you can access your properties of each combobox.

Comment: It might help, but what if I would like to create more than one group of comboBoxes?

Comment: You could make groups on a panel. Then iterate each panel, this way you can get "groups". Not the best way, but it would work.